# How can I type the words like this - please check picture?

Tags: discussion

Consider:

> [image]

I just want to say, the words detector is too strict. It seems I can't type anything.

Comment: I can't view the picture what you typed

Comment: well you seem to try to post the answer in Chinese, you should use English in this site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231093/when-listviews-item-is-click-how-to-make-its-view-color-to-be-red-others-is-bl/40231261#40231261

Comment: actually ，蓝瘦 香菇 is my modal particle. I can't type so many words in my answers ,such as  the view  ,look at the ，set it

Comment: @Jafir writing in chinese because you get warning in English just means your answer will be deleted as pure crap, because we only do English here.... There has to be better ways to express what you have to say that the parser will not jump on

Comment: Btw, this is blocked as spam rather than low quality because we've dealt with numerous spam posts written in Chinese in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're not writing in English:

> [image]

I'd argue this is a perfectly fine "catch", as far as the bad words detector is concerned. SO is English-only, that's why that answer was blocked.

Comment: I can't type english words  like 'the view ',so I type chinese

Comment: Can you please show the full text that caused the error message, rather than what you typed in afterwards?

Comment: @Pekka웃: I assume you're talking to Jafir there?

Comment: @Cerbrus yup! ---